# If $V$ is a vector space over an infinite field $F$ such that dim$V =2$, then the number of distinct subspace $V$ has....$?$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space over an infinite field $F$ such that dim$V =2$, then the number of distinct subspace $V$ has....$?$

I know how to count number of distinct subspaces for finite field. What about an infinite field$?$

I think it should be infinite, but answer key says it's $2$, which should be incorrect I guess.

Am I right$?$

Comment: In $R^{2}$ we can generate different subspaces by $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4).....$ and so on, all are distinct.

Comment: The answer $2$ would only be correct for $\dim V=1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Since $\dim(V)=2$ you can find $\{u,v \}$ a basis. For each $\alpha \in F$ define $$V_\alpha := \mathbb F (u+\alpha v)$$

Show that these spaces are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. For each $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$, $Fv$ is a subspace of $V$ and $v\notin Fw\implies Fv\neq Fw$. So, there are infinitely many subspaces.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.